# Recursive feature elimination using multioutput estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to undertake recursive feature elimination using a multiouput model. I included a minimum reproducible example below:

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline 
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, make_scorer 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV 
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

data = {"salary": [60000, 50000, 10000, 94000, 34000, 70000], "age": [23, 27, 13, 45, 60, 70], "weight": [80, 90, 50, 75, 60, 70], "height": [90, 100, 70, 60, 50, 70], }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data) 

y = np.asarray([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]])

model = MultiOutputClassifier(CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0)) 

pipe = Pipeline(steps = [("preprocessor", StandardScaler()), ("estimator", model)])

rfe_cv_pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RFECV(estimator=model, scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score), min_features_to_select=2, importance_getter="estimator.feature_importances_", cv=2))

scores = cross_validate(pipe, df, y, cv=2, return_train_score=True) 

rfe_cv_pipe.fit(df, y)
```

I am able to get training and validation scores by applying the cross_validate function on the pipe and on my dataframe and target, however when I call the fit method using the `rfe_cv_pipe` object, I get an input contains NaN, infinity, or a value too large for `dtype('float64')`.

Full error trace:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 427, in fit
    self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 726, in fit
    scores = parallel(
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 727, in <genexpr>
    func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 32, in _rfe_single_fit
    return rfe._fit(
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_rfe.py", line 300, in _fit
    importances = _get_feature_importances(
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_base.py", line 239, in _get_feature_importances
    importances = safe_sqr(importances).sum(axis=0)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 712, in safe_sqr
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=["csr", "csc", "coo"], ensure_2d=False)
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 957, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 122, in _assert_all_finite
    _assert_all_finite_element_wise(
  File "/Users/name/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 171, in _assert_all_finite_element_wise
    raise ValueError(msg_err)
ValueError: Input contains NaN.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the traceback that it's the feature importances that end up raising that NaN error. The `RFECV` is operating on the `MultiOutputClassifier`, so you'll need to aggregate the importances of the fitted `estimators_`, see e.g. [Can I show feature importance for MultiOutputClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54562464/10495893)

Comment: Thanks a lot I managed to figure it out.